# Kotlin hacer un random con decimales

Tags: kotlin

¿como se puede hacer un random con decimales en kotlin?

Quiero hacer esto:

```
var numero = (1..10000).random()
```

Pero que me salga un numero random con dos decimales.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! has buscado en google? En la documentacion de [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/next-double.html) ya dicen como hacer randoms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para generar con decimales debes utilizar `Random.nextDouble` y luego redondear hacia la cantidad de decimales que quieras, por ejemplo:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var numero = Random.nextDouble(1.0, 10000.0)
    // Formato con String Format
    println("%.2f".format(numero))

    // Formato con DecimalFormat
    val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
    println(df.format(numero))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes declarar una variable **DecimalFormat** y con esta asignarle el formato:

```
double min = 1
double max = 10000
Random r = new Random()
double numero = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble()

val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
println(df.format(numero))
```

Tenés que importar las siguientes librerías:

```
import java.math.RoundingMode
import java.text.DecimalFormat
```

Saludos.

Comment: Cuando hago el println me sale un un numero entero, no con los decimales

Comment: Ah había interpretado mal, ahí actualicé el código